# Is there a tutorial on how to present info on "Ask Ubuntu"?

Tags: discussion

Example: How to paste info from Ubuntu Settings Details About? Could be useful to identify my system.

Comment: What info is exactly relevant depends on the question. All info can be retrieved from cli. You will usually be requested to run the corresponding command, and add the output to the question.

Comment: This question belongs on "meta"

Comment: @dobey I'm not so sure. This is a general question about how to provide system information. I suspect it is a duplicate of something, but [in spite of the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/185080), it seems to me that this question is much more about Ubuntu itself than about Ask Ubuntu. Note that the body of this post consists entirely of a specific technical question about how to do something in Ubuntu.

Comment: @EliahKagan Well, the body is stated as an example of one set of possible information that could be provided, as a means to further the question in the title; which appears to be about how to use the site more than how to use Ubuntu. The example question also isn't "how do I get the info from settings?" but rather "how do I paste that info into a question here?"

Answer (score 12):

You can get all info you see in the 'Settings → About' Dialogbox in terminal. For example if you want to know your Ubuntu version you can use the following command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

For identifying your wireless network cards:

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
```

For identifying your ethernet cards:

```
lspci -nn | grep Ethernet
```

For identifying your drives:

```
blkid
lsblk
df -h
fdisk -l
```

For showing file/directory information:

```
stat <filename/directory>
file <filename/directory>
```

For identifying which services are currently running:

```
service --status-all
systemctl --state running --type service
```

For seeing what happens when you connect a USB device (you have 30 seconds after typing this command to connect your device):

```
timeout  --signal=KILL 30s journalctl --follow
```

And this is just to name a few, there are more but that depends on what info you want to give. All text can be copied from terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and pasted on AskUbuntu with simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: @funlight two hyphens: `--state` and `--type`

Comment: @Videonauth I think the topic of the question is great (but will be missed by new uers because it's here and not in a tutorial) but when they start to delve into the syntax of the command...  I will delete my comment in a short bit.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now, that my title and the body make up two items.

Tutorial: I can get some info from reading answers, but as a newbie, I would prefer to read a tutorial with the guidelines that have highest priority for the expert helpers.

Info from Ubuntu: I would like to present some standard info about my system – concurrently with my question. By doing so, it will be easier for experts to decide immediately, whether question and system is “my table” or not. It could increase efficiency for all.

System info workaround: I made a document merely with the values from Settings-Details-About. A question could be followed by pasting this info (no descriptions):

Ubuntu 17.10-Lenovo IdeaPad Z500-3.8 GiB-Intel® Core™ i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8- GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2-3.26.2-32-bit-980.3 GB

Is this good enough, or can Ubuntu give me even more info by a keystroke -which I easily can present for Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: An important point is that the information you show has to be somewhat relevant - unless you're having graphics problems, your graphics card is irrelevant. Your CPU is irrelevant for the vast majority of problems. Likewise with your hard disk size, RAM, etc. Try to keep information relevant, please, or it's just noise that distracts

Comment: OK. I will keep that in mind.